# What does the  DOS command "findstr" do here?

Tags: windows, command, dos, prompt, findstr

From my understanding of findstr, it looks for text within files.  What, then, is making it search for a pattern in the filename itself?

```
dir | findstr "test[0-9][0-9][0-9]test"
```

Does the pipe alter its behavior?  Someone explain the inner working of this.  I know it works, but I don't understand how it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe redirects the standard output of `dir` to the standard input of `findstr`, this works as `findstr` will use either the arguments passed to it on the command line, or anything passed to it via stdin.

Comment: I think I get it now.  So instead of reading a file line by line, it is now reading a list of filenames line by line?

Comment: The output of dir the dir command is written directly to findstr, so its equivalent to `dir > temp.txt & findstr [pattern] temp.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `findstr` itself, but it looks to be similar to [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

What it does here is take the output of `dir` (the directory listing) and search for some string in that output. It then only outputs those lines that match (effectively searching in the directory listing).

[This process (called piping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_%28Unix%29) is pretty common in Unix-like operating systems. As you see it also exists on Windows (and DOS before that).